# Is there any way to "Clear Site Data" of browser with code?

Tags: javascript, python, memory, browser, browser-cache

When my webpage query is executing long, the website looks like it froze to an average user. Therefore, I was hoping to add a button to cancel the query and the load.

To do currently, I would have to F12 (in Chrome), go to `Application` with `Clear Storage`, and then click `Clear site data`. Is there any way to do that through code?

I tried clearing cookies, local storage, session storage. Doesn't seem to work unless I `Clear site data`.

Comment: I'm confused about what the stored site data has to do with stopping execution? Does `window.stop()` not work?

Comment: It does not work in my case because it seems the query has to finish running before further user interactions can be made. This is probably from using mod_python and using content-type "application/force-download" and executing the query with fdb cursor and returning 'apache.ok'. Most likely, I'm going to do some user input validation in javascript to prevent the long query from running first.

Comment: You don't need user interaction; you can call `window.stop()` from your code automatically if the page is taking too long to load. If you can't even get that to run, then no code you could write will run, either, so there's nothing you can do at that point except let it run to completion. (I don't understand why clearing the site data would abort the loading in the first place, though :/ )

Comment: window.stop() is equivalent to pressing the X "Stop loading this page" (located before the web address in Chrome) correct? Manually clicking the X doesn't stop the query from needing to finish loading.

Comment: It is. What kind of query is this? I may have misread what you meant. I thought the page loading itself was taking too long and you wanted to stop that. Is this an AJAX query you're talking about? How are you making it? (Fetch, jQuery, XHR, etc.?) I didn't think it was AJAX because AJAX shouldn't lock up your site while it runs...

Comment: To run the query, I'm using python's fdb cursor to execute the query and mod_python to download the results into a csv file. If I do "Clean the Site Data", I am able to interact with the webpage again and then make another search query download while the other slow query can finish downloading.

Comment: Oh, so this is a server-side DATABASE query? That's quite different. I'm still not sure why clearing site data on the client side would abort that, but this is not a problem you can solve with Javascript. The query is running on the server, so it needs to be aborted on the server, not the client. I don't know anything about FDB, so I can't help your further, but I hope this at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Correct, it is a server-side query. No problem, thanks for the responses.